# Compare multiple columns within same row and highlight differences in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-styles

I have a dataframe similar to:

| NAME | DB1 | DB2 | DB3 | DB4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| WORKFLOW_1 | workflow1-1.jar | workflow1-2.jar | workflow1-1.jar | workflow1-3.jar |
| WORKFLOW_2 | workflow2-1.jar | workflow2-1.jar | workflow2-1.jar | workflow2-1.jar |
| WORKFLOW_3 | workflow3-2.jar | workflow3-1.jar | workflow3-1.jar | workflow3-1.jar |
| WORKFLOW_4 |  | workflow4-1.jar |  |  |

Where **NAME** is the key for this table throughout ***n*** databases. I'm gathering data from an specific column and merging it side by side for further analysis.

My problem is that I need to highlight rows which contains different filenames between columns DB**n**.

I've tried the solution below:

```py
        def highlight(row):

        for key1, column1 in row.items():
            if key1 != 'NAME':
                for key2, column2 in row.items():
                    if key2 != 'NAME':
                        if column1 != column2:
                            return ['background-color: red']
        return ['background-color: green']

        pd = pd.style.apply(highlight)
```

I tried to style the entire row when at least one filename is different from the others, but it did not work, when I export to excel, only the first line is red, which is not even one of the cases where it should happen.

Comment: Just to be sure, what should be highlighted in your example? All DB columns for WORKFLOW_1 - WORKFLOW_3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest (and naïve) approach is to use [Series.eq](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) to test each row against the first value. Setting an appropriate `subset` is very important here, as we only want to compare against other similar values.

```
def highlight_row(s: pd.Series) -> List[str]:
    bg_color = 'red'
    if s.eq(s[0]).all():
        bg_color = 'green'
    return [f'background-color:{bg_color}'] * len(s)


df.style.apply(
    func=highlight_row,
    subset=['DB1', 'DB2', 'DB3', 'DB4'],
    axis=1
)
```

[image: Styled table with naïve styling (considers empty string and nan when doing comparison)]

---

We can be a bit less naïve by excluding empty string and null values (and any other invalid values) from each row with a boolean indexing before doing the equality comparison with just the filtered array:

```
def highlight_row(s: pd.Series) -> List[str]:
    filtered_s = s[s.notnull() & ~s.eq('')]
    # Check for completely empty row (prevents index error from filtered_s[0])
    if filtered_s.empty:
        # No valid values in row
        css_str = ''
    elif filtered_s.eq(filtered_s[0]).all():
        # All values are the same
        css_str = 'background-color: green'
    else:
        # Row Values Differ
        css_str = 'background-color: red'
    return [css_str] * len(s)
```

We can also leverage an [IndexSlice](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.IndexSlice.html) to more dynamically select the columns for the `subset` instead of manually passing a list of column names:

```
df.style.apply(
    func=highlight_row,
    subset=pd.IndexSlice[:, 'DB1':],
    axis=1
)
```

[image: Styled table that considers only "valid" values for equality comparison]

---

Lastly, it is possible to instead pass the idx/cols to the styling function instead of subsetting if wanting the entire row to be highlighted:

```
def highlight_row(s: pd.Series, idx: pd.IndexSlice) -> List[str]:
    css_str = 'background-color: red'
    # Filter Columns
    filtered_s = s[idx]
    # Filter Values
    filtered_s = filtered_s[filtered_s.notnull() & ~filtered_s.eq('')]
    # Check for completely empty row
    if filtered_s.empty:
        css_str = ''  # Empty row Styles
    elif filtered_s.eq(filtered_s[0]).all():
        css_str = 'background-color: green'
    return [css_str] * len(s)


df.style.apply(
    func=highlight_row,
    idx=pd.IndexSlice['DB1':],  # 1D IndexSlice!
    axis=1
)
```

[image: Styled table with entire row highlighting]

---

Setup and Imports:

```
from typing import List

import pandas as pd  # version 1.4.2

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'NAME': ['WORKFLOW_1', 'WORKFLOW_2', 'WORKFLOW_3', 'WORKFLOW_4'],
    'DB1': ['workflow1-1.jar', 'workflow2-1.jar', 'workflow3-2.jar', ''],
    'DB2': ['workflow1-2.jar', 'workflow2-1.jar', 'workflow3-1.jar',
            'workflow4-1.jar'],
    'DB3': ['workflow1-1.jar', 'workflow2-1.jar', 'workflow3-1.jar', ''],
    'DB4': ['workflow1-3.jar', 'workflow2-1.jar', 'workflow3-1.jar', '']
})
```